# ¿Como crear una database in memory con MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, oracle

Tengo este trabajo de montar una database in memory, pues la cosa es que e estado buscando pero no he podido encontrar un trabajo o algo así de un paso a paso, necesito saber cómo hacer eso ya sea con MySQL u Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría servir para el Wiki:

## El motor de almacenamiento MEMORY (HEAP) en MySQL

El motor de almacenamiento MEMORY crea tablas con contenidos que se almacenan en memoria. Éstas se conocían préviamente como HEAP . En MySQL 5.0, MEMORY es el término preferido, aunque HEAP se soporta para compatibilidad con versiones anteriores.

Cada tabla MEMORY está asociada con un fichero de disco. El nombre de fichero comienza con el nombre de la tabla y tiene una exensión de .frm para indicar que almacena la definición de la tabla.

Para especificar explícitamente que quiere una tabla MEMORY, indíquelo con una opción ENGINE:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

Como indica su nombre, las tablas MEMORY se almacenan en memoria y usan índices hash por defecto. Esto las hace muy rápidas, y muy útiles para crear tablas temporales. Sin embargo, **cuando se apaga el servidor, todos los datos almacenados en las tablas MEMORY se pierden**. Las tablas por sí mismas continúan existiendo ya que sus definiciones se almacenan en ficheros .frm en disco, **pero están vacías cuando reinicia el servidor**.

Ejemplo de creación de una tabla MEMORY :

```
CREATE TABLE test ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
SELECT ip,SUM(downloads) AS down
         FROM log_table GROUP BY ip; 
SELECT COUNT(ip),AVG(down) FROM test;
```

Ejemplo para borrar la tabla:

```
DROP TABLE test;
```

Las tablas MEMORY tienen las siguientes **características**:

- El espacio para tablas MEMORY se reserva en pequeños bloques.
- Las tablas usan el 100% del hashing dinámico para insrciones.
- No se necesita área de desbordamiento o espacio extra para claves.
- No se necesita espacio extra para listas libres.
- Los registros borrados se ponen en una lista encadenada y se reúsan
  cuando inserta nuevos datos en la tabla.
- Las tablas MEMORY no tienen ninguno de los problemas asociados con
  borrados más inserciones en tablas hasheadas.
- Las tablas MEMORY pueden tener hasta 32 índices por tabla, 16
  columnas por índice y una clave de longitud máxima de 500 bytes.
- En MySQL 5.0, el motor MEMORY implementa índices HASH y BTREE . Puede
  espcificar uno u otro para cada índice añadiendo una cláusula USING
  tal y como se muestra:

  CREATE TABLE lookup
      (id INT, INDEX USING HASH (id))
      ENGINE = MEMORY;

  CREATE TABLE lookup
      (id INT, INDEX USING BTREE (id))
      ENGINE = MEMORY;
- Las características generales de B-trees e índices hash se describen
  en Sección 7.4.5, “Cómo utiliza MySQL los índices”.
- Puede tener claves no únicas en una tabla MEMORY. (Esta es una
  característica no común de implementaciones de índices hash.)
- En MySQL 5.0, puede usar INSERT DELAYED con tablas MEMORY . Consulte
  Sección 13.2.4.2, “Sintaxis de INSERT DELAYED”.
- Si tiene un índice hash en una tabla MEMORY que tenga un alto índice
  de duplicación de claves (muchas entradas de índice con el mismo
  valor), las actualizaciones a la tabla que afecten valores claves y
  todos los borrados son significativamente más lentos. El rango de
  esta ralentización es proporcional al rango de duplicación (o
  inversamente proporcional al grado cardinalidad). Pude usar un índice
  BTREE para evitar este problema.
- Las tablas MEMORY usan una longitud de registro fija.
- MEMORY no soporta columnas BLOB o TEXT .
- MEMORY en MySQL 5.0 incluye soporte para columnas AUTO_INCREMENT e
  índices en columnas que contengan valores NULL .
- Las tablas MEMORY se comparten entre todos los clientes (como
  cualquier otra tabla no-TEMPORARY).
- Los contenidos de las tablas MEMORY se almacenan en memora , lo que
  es una propiedad que las tablas MEMORY comparten con las tablas
  internas que el servidor va creando al procesar consultas. Sin
  embargo, los dos tipos de tablas difierne en que las tablas MEMORY no
  están sujetas a conversión de almacenamiento, mientras que las tablas
  internas sí:
- Si una tabla interna llega a ser demasiado grande, el servidor la
  convierte automáticamente a una tabla en disco. El límite de tamaño
  lo determina la variable de sistema tmp_table_size .
- Las tablas MEMORY nunca se convieren en tablas de disco. Para segurar
  que no comete un error accidentalmente, puede cambiar la variable de
  sistema max_heap_table_size para que imponga un tamaño máximo de
  tablas MEMORY . Para tablas individuales, puede especificar la opción
  de tabla MAX_ROWS en el comando CREATE TABLE .
- El servidor necesita suficiente memoria para mantener todas las
  tablas MEMORY en uso a la vez.
- Para liberar memoria usada por una tabla MEMORY cuando no se requiere
  su contenido, debe ejecutar DELETE FROM o TRUNCATE TABLE, o borrar
  toda la tabla con DROP TABLE.
- Si quiere rellenar una tabla MEMORY cuando arranca el servidor MySQL,
  puede usar la opción --init-file . Por ejemplo, puede usar comandos
  como INSERT INTO ... SELECT o LOAD DATA INFILE en este fichero para
  cargar la tabla de una fuente de datos persistente. Consulte Sección
  5.3.1, “Opciones del comando mysqld” y Sección 13.2.5, “Sintaxis de LOAD DATA INFILE”.
- Si usa replicación, las tablas MEMORY del servidor maestro se vacían
  cuando se apaga y reinicia. Sin embargo, un esclavo no es consciente
  que se vacían estas tablas, así que retorna contenido desfasado si
  selecciona datos del mismo. En MySQL 5.0, cuando se usa una tabla
  MEMORY en el maestro por primera vez desde que arrancó el maestro, se
  escribe un comando DELETE FROM en el log binario del maestro
  automáticamente, resincronizando el maestro y el esclavo otra vez.
  Tenga en cuenta que incluso con esta estrategia, el esclavo tiene
  datos desfasados en la tabla en el intervalo entre el reinicio del
  maestro y el primer uso de la tabla. Sin embargo, si usa la opción
  --init-file para rellenar la tabla MEMORY al arrancar el maestro, se asegura que este intervalo sea cero.
- La memoria necesaria por un registro en una tabla MEMORY se calcula
  con la siguiente expresión:

  SUM_OVER_ALL_BTREE_KEYS(max_length_of_key + sizeof(char*) * 4)  + SUM_OVER_ALL_HASH_KEYS(sizeof(char*) * 2) + ALIGN(length_of_row+1, sizeof(char*))

ALIGN() representa un factor de redondeo para que la longitud del registro sea un múltiplo exacto del tamaño del puntero char . sizeof(char*) es 4 en máquinas de 32-bit y 8 en máquinas de 64-bit.

Fuente: Ayuda de Mysql, traducida en [este sitio](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/es/memory-storage-engine.html).

Comment: amigo pero podría sincronizar esta base de datos con otra o crear una tabla de forma tradicional para guardar los datos en caso de un corte de luz los datos no se pierdan